# APEX Interactive Grid - new line in row

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

What is the best way to put a new line in IG values?

I have a long value in column because of concatenation of couple of columns. I tried with `||chr(10)||` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Column Type is `Display Only`, you can include `<br>` where you want the line breaks, then make sure you turn off Escape Special Characters for that column, otherwise `<br>` will be printed with your value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked!